# Using twisted to serve gzipped JavaScript

Tags: python, gzip, twisted

I tried to use EncodingResourceWrappper and GzipEncoderFactory to gzip my twisted web server responses.

This seems to work for most files. But I can not serve JavaScript files which are later loaded via requirejs. (The browser (Chrome or Firefox) simply keeps spinning.

<strike>The files serve fine, when I enter the JavaScript source path as URL.</strike> [Updated: No, because they came out of the browser cache]

The files serve fine from AppEngine (which also gzips them).

```
class SharedRoot(resource.Resource):
"""Root resource that combines the two sites/entry points"""
WSGI = None

def getChild(self, child, request):
    request.prepath.pop()
    request.postpath.insert(0, child)
    return self.WSGI

def render(self, request):
    return self.WSGI.render(request)

def render_POST(self, request):
    logger.debug(pformat(request.__dict__))
    newdata = request.content.getvalue()
    logger.debug(newdata)
    return ''

class WildcardResource(resource.Resource):

def __init__(self, childResource):
    resource.Resource.__init__(self)
    self.childResource=childResource

def getChild(self,child, request):
    return self.childResource


class GzipFileResource(static.File):        
    def getChild(self, path, request):
    child = super(GzipFileResource, self).getChild(path, request)            
    return EncodingResourceWrapper(child, [GzipEncoderFactory()])

class DynamicFile(GzipFileResource):
    def render_GET(self, request):
    request.setHeader("Cache-Control", ["no-cache"])
    request.setHeader("Pragma", ["no-cache"])
    request.setHeader("Expires", ["Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"])

    return super(DynamicFile, self).render_GET(request)



shared=SharedRoot()
shared.WSGI=EncodingResourceWrapper(wsgiResource,[GzipEncoderFactory()]) 
shared.putChild("static",GzipFileResource("static"))
shared.putChild("css", GzipFileResource("static/css"))
shared.putChild("js",WildcardResource(GzipFileResource("source")))
```

Any ideas?

Updated:

Traces and debugging have shown, that the problem occurs with script files > 64 KB, where the first call to the gzip compression object just returns the gzip header (that I can see in the network trace) and the 2nd call returns nothing (because the rest of the compressed output would happen with the flush call (that I can not see in the network trace)).

Testing with an increased buffer size (of the abstract.FileDescriptor) did not solve the problem

Comment: Try to download JavaScript with curl or wget with detailed information print.

Comment: According to the network trace, just the gzip header is transferred